# Does Android USB Host mode supports USB 1.1 devices?

Tags: android, usb

I have a Motorola Xoom and I have been working on an application to detect certain USB devices, the problem I'm having is that one device is USB 2.0 and another one is USB 1.1. I can detect the USB 2.0 device OK but not the USB 1.1, I have tried other USB 1.1 devices and still no luck. Does anyone knows if there is support for USB 1.1 devices?

Comment: You might try posting this on http://android.stackexchange.com for information on your specific device.

Answer (score 0):

1.1 should be fine, I am able to detect [a 1.1 device](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0011DYG1O/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i00) without issue.

[I did have problems with it in the initial investigations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339312/android-usbhost-mode-why-does-my-irda-device-fail-on-claiminterface) however where the OS detected the device and let me interrogate it but refused to let me actually claim it for use. This turned out to be due to the USB device demanding more power than my phone was willing or able to supply.